# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in sql.php on line 195

Tags: php

tengo una pregunta sobre este error, siempre aparece en el encabezado de mi sitio web de prueba.

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in sql.php on line 195

> Este error se refiere a la línea elseif($login_level['group_status'] === '0'):

```
 /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Find current log in user by session id
  /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
  function current_user(){
      static $current_user;
      global $db;
      if(!$current_user){
         if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])):
             $user_id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
             $current_user = find_by_id('users',$user_id);
        endif;
      }
    return $current_user;
  }
 /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Function for cheaking which user level has access to page
  /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
   function page_require_level($require_level){
     global $session;
     $current_user = current_user();
     $login_level = find_by_groupLevel($current_user['user_level']);
     //if user not login
     if (!$session->isUserLoggedIn(true)):
            $session->msg('d','Por favor Iniciar sesión...');
            redirect('index.php', false);
      //if Group status Deactive
     elseif($login_level['group_status'] === '0'):
           $session->msg('d','Este nivel de usuario esta inactivo!');
           redirect('home.php',false);
           
      //cheackin log in User level and Require level is Less than or equal to
     elseif($current_user['user_level'] <= (int)$require_level):
              return true;
      else:
            $session->msg("d", "¡Lo siento!  no tienes permiso para ver la página.");
            redirect('home.php', false);
        endif;

     }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la respuesta.

Comment: el problema es que en algun momento esto no existe: `$login_level['group_status']`

Answer (score 0):

pues primero que nada, el error te menciona claramente, que estás tratando de obtener un offset, cuando el retorno es un booleano. 
Por lo que agrega un `var_dump()` luego del `$login_level`.

```
$login_level = find_by_groupLevel($current_user['user_level']);
var_dump($login_level);
```

Si todo esto es correcto, `$login_level` no debería retornar ni *true* ni *false*.
Si este está retornando un true o false, es un error, y no estás obteniendo la info que quieres.

---

Además quería detallarte algo en la comparación de `group_status`
Estás haciendo una comparación estricta, pero asi no puedes comparar.

Te lo ejemplifico: El siguiente código dará false, por que la comparación la haces estricta, y estás consultando si $true con el valor true, es un '1', lo que seria un string con el caracter 1.

```
$true = true;
if($true === '1'){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Hola @Excorpion agregue: var_dump($login_level); 
y me ha regresado lo siguiente: bool(false)

Comment: Exacto, eso significa que `find_by_groupLevel` no está regresando los datos como debería.

Comment: En donde le estás pasando `$current_user` a la funcion ?

Comment: Edito arriba escribo funcion de $current_user

Comment: Y la funcion esa, te esta retornando valores o tampoco ?

Comment: `array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(15) "Bernardo Patino"
  ["username"]=>
  string(5) "Khoug"
  ["password"]=>
  string(40) "example"
  ["user_level"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["image"]=>
  string(13) "noplx51q1.png"
  ["status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["last_login"]=>
  string(19) "2021-07-15 00:53:53"
}`

Comment: Esto es lo que me arroja el var_dump de $current_user

Comment: Yo lo veo ahí en la segunda linea del comentario, me parece que si esta. (https://github.com/siamon123/warehouse-inventory-system) en este repositorio de Github esta el código que estoy intentando de poner a funcionar pero me aparecen algunos errores, podría simplemente ponerle error report 0 y solucionado, sin embargo no se si eso me podría generar problemas.

Comment: Perdon me equivoque ayer, el que no existe es ´group_status´

Answer (score 0):

Hola compañeros lo solucione... es con "d" comillas dobles

// if Group status Deactive
elseif($login_level['group_status'] === '0'): $session->msg("d",'Este nivel de usuario esta inactivo!'); redirect('home.php',false);